# addClass() removeClass() issues in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hello friends heres my code

**Jquery**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#sitemap').children('li').addClass('cl');

        $('.cl').mouseenter(function() {
            $(this).css('background','#eee');
            $(this).siblings('li').css('background','');
            $(this).parents().css('background','');
        })

        $('.cl').mouseout(function() {
            $(this).css('background','');
        })
    })
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<ul id="sitemap">
    <li>
        one
        <ul>
            <li>two</li>
            <li>two</li>
            <li>two</li>
            <li>two</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>one</li>
    <li>one</li>
</ul>
```

i am getting confused how to solve my problem actually i want a simple effect when `mouseenter()` on `<li>` background color will change .. but when I use nested list then its not working fine . I want when user hover the li the background color will change

Please help me

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: do you want an effect or you want only to change the color?

Comment: i only want to change the background color @Th0rndike

Answer (score 3):

You don't really need JavaScript for this, just use CSS

```
  #sitemap li {
  background-color:white;
  }

  #sitemap li:hover {
  background-color:red;
  }
```

you can also add any other selectors you require.

Comment: Worth noting that this doesn't work in IE6 (and only IE7 in standards mode). Others are fine. In case the OP is developing for an east asian audience (where IE6 isn't yet dead).

Answer (score 1):

If you're in standards mode and you don't need to support IE6, you can do this with just CSS:

```
.cl:hover {
    background: #eee;
}
```

No JavaScript required. Unfortunately, IE6 only respects `:hover` on `a` elements. Also note that you need to be standards (not quirks) mode for it to work correctly in IE7.

---

**Update**: Based on your comment below:

> problem is when i use nested list then this code will change all nested `<li>` background color

It sounds to me like you want to be highlighting something more specific than the `li`, then, because setting the top-level `li`'s background color will color it **and** its descendant elements (unless they have an override color, which would be ugly in the case of your first item with the `ul` in it). I think I'd change the structure:

```
<ul id="sitemap">
    <li>
        <div>one</div>
        <ul>
            <li><div>two</div></li>
            <li><div>two</div></li>
            <li><div>two</div></li>
            <li><div>two</div></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><div>one</div></li>
    <li><div>one</div></li>
</ul>
```

...and then use this CSS:

```
#sitemap div:hover {
    background: #eee;
}
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/uhereg) | [source](http://jsbin.com/uhereg/edit#html)

Comment: you are right but problem is when i use nested list then this code will change all nested <li> background color . this is the main error who bring me here

Comment: @Kamal: So you want the highlight to be **individual** `li` elements, including the ones in the submenu?

Comment: It's IE6 in which `:hover` only works on `a`. In IE7, it works on all elements (provided you're in standards mode as opposed to quirks mode).

Comment: @thirtydot: Thanks!! I looked it up, but the reference I found was wrong. I just tried it, and you're absolutely right. Excellent! IE6 being effectively dead outside east Asia, that's great news.

Comment: @Kamal: See update. If you don't need to support IE6, you're golden.

Answer (score 1):

Please `Update` your `jquery` with following code

```
$(function() {
    $("#sitemap").children("li").each(function() {
        $(this).mouseover(function() {
            $(this).css ("background-Color", "#c0c0c0");
        });
        $(this).mouseout(function () {
            $(this).css("background-Color", "#FFF"); 
        });
    });
});​
```

see this Jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/v4CL5/

Hope this is helpful for you

Comment: thanks for help but your code change nested lists background color in one shot .. i want to change every <li> background color change on mouseover

Answer (score 0):

The `.children()` function only goes down one level of the DOM, so your selector will only match the `<li>` elements that are directly below the `<ul>` with ID `sitemap`. Use the `.find()` function instead to match all `<li>` elements inside that element, regardless of which level of the DOM they're on.

That said, I'm not really sure why you're using jQuery to add the class if you have access to the HTML.

Comment: actually i want to apply this code on my html dynamically . this is why i using jquery

Answer (score 0):

just change

```
$('#sitemap').children('li')
```

into

```
$('#sitemap li')
```

since `children()` is looking for *immediate* children of `#sitemap` list (and not also  for sub-nested list-items)

Comment: used this in my code but when u first time hover the nested `<li>` it will change all childrens background color check here http://jsfiddle.net/TdgX3/

Answer (score 0):

This should start you out, although I think its a bit clunky how I had to turn off all of the child 'ul li':

http://jsfiddle.net/Ashenkase/weHBT/